# How to convert linestring to multiple longitude latitude column in geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

Here's my one row of input

```
Name                    geometry
Jalan W.R. Supratman    LINESTRING (95.317339 5.5603499, 95.3169007 5.5602832, 95.3165735 5.5602391, 95.3161729 5.5602097, 95.3161289 5.5601326, 95.3160873 5.5600178)
```

Here's my expected output

```
Name                                  Langitude         Longitude
Jalan W.R. Supratman                  95.317339         5.5603499
Jalan W.R. Supratman                  95.3169007        5.5602832
Jalan W.R. Supratman                  95.3165735        5.5602391
Jalan W.R. Supratman                  95.3161729        5.5602097
Jalan W.R. Supratman                  95.3161289        5.5601326
Jalan W.R. Supratman                  95.3160873        5.5600178
```

**Edit:**

Here's what I try

```
def utm_to_latlon(coords, zone_number, zone_letter):
    easting = coords[0]
    northing = coords[1]
    return utm.to_latlon(easting, northing, zone_number, zone_letter)

# Using nested list comprehension
df ["lat_lon_tuple"] = [[utm_to_latlon(xy, 44, "N") for xy in tuple(geom.coords)] for geom in df.geometry]
```

The error message

```
<ipython-input-5-4dfd2badb8b4> in <listcomp>(.0)
      5 
      6 # Using nested list comprehension
----> 7 df ["lat_lon_tuple"] = [[utm_to_latlon(xy, 44, "N") for xy in tuple(geom.coords)] for geom in df.geometry]

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'coords'
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: when asking about errors, please always include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the coordinates defining the [`LineString`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#LineString) with the `coords` attribute, then convert this to a [`shapely.geometry.MultiPoint`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#MultiPoint):

```py
df['geometry'] = df['geometry'].apply(
    lambda x: shapely.geometry.MultiPoint(list(x.coords))
)
```

Once this is done, you can use [`df.explode`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explode.html):

```py
In [10]: df.explode(index_parts=False)
Out[10]:
                   geometry
0  POINT (95.31734 5.56035)
0  POINT (95.31690 5.56028)
0  POINT (95.31657 5.56024)
0  POINT (95.31617 5.56021)
0  POINT (95.31613 5.56013)
0  POINT (95.31609 5.56002)
```

Answer (score 3):

`Explode` with index and then apply `Series`:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString

df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    {'Name': ['Jalan W.R. Supratman', 'Other Street'],
     'geometry': [LineString([(95.317339, 5.5603499), (95.3169007,5.5602832), (95.3165735, 5.5602391), (95.3161729,5.5602097), (95.3161289, 5.5601326), (95.3160873, 5.5600178)]),
                  LineString([(95.0, 6.0), (95.01, 6.01)])]})

print(df.set_index('Name').geometry
        .apply(lambda x: list(x.coords))
        .explode(ignore_index=False)
        .apply(pd.Series)
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={0: 'Langitude', 1: 'Longitude'}))
```

Result:

```
                   Name  Langitude  Longitude
0  Jalan W.R. Supratman  95.317339   5.560350
1  Jalan W.R. Supratman  95.316901   5.560283
2  Jalan W.R. Supratman  95.316574   5.560239
3  Jalan W.R. Supratman  95.316173   5.560210
4  Jalan W.R. Supratman  95.316129   5.560133
5  Jalan W.R. Supratman  95.316087   5.560018
6          Other Street  95.000000   6.000000
7          Other Street  95.010000   6.010000
```